# Синхронизация данных с удаленного сайта

Tags: php, ajax, json, curl

Есть сайт 1 в котором есть таблица, рейсов, которая обновляется.
Есть сайт 2, в нем нужно отображать эту таблицу с рейсами.

Так как у сайта 1 нет специального кода для вставки, то нужно создать как бы парсер данных с сайта 1 на сайт 2.

Вопрос, как лучше это сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужен алгоритм действий:

1. получение содержимого страницы сайта 1 с таблицей (источник)
2. разбор html разметки и извлечение нужных значений (например [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/))
3. обработка значений (например, исключение дубляжа значений)
4. запись значений в БД
5. вешаем скрипт на [cron](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=others&page=009) с указанием периодичности выполнения
6. на нужной странице сайта 2 выводим данные с БД

Либо же уточните вопрос, и напишите с какими проблемами Вы столкнулись при выполнения данной задачи

Comment: А не будет проблем с идентификаторами?

Comment: Нужно смотреть исходную таблицу. Запрос очень общий. Возможно есть индентификаторы записей с исходной таблице, их и нужно будет использовать.

Comment: Общий принцип понял, думал возможно как-то можно сделать проще.

Comment: Возможно у них есть api для доступа к таким данным? Гараздо проще будет

Comment: Да я тоже об этом подумал, выясню на прямую, просто сервис у них отличный.

Comment: и ссылочку можете дать на сервис?